# TypeScript import value is a file name instead of its content

Tags: typescript

I need to import content of a file of custom extension as a string.

(I have WebGL vertex shader in a file called `simple.vert`)

I created a file `extensions.d.ts`

```
declare module '*.vert' {
    const value: string;
    export default value;
}
```

Then, in `component.ts` I write:

```
import SimpleVert from '../../shaders/simple.vert';
console.log(SimpleVert);
```

Unfortunately, `typeof Simplevert === 'string'` but the value of `SimpleVert` is `/static/media/simple.e32079ee.vert` which is a name of file to import I guess, instead of file content.

Furthermore, when I try to `require(SimpleVert)` the error is thrown:

```
Error: Cannot find module '/static/media/simple.e32079ee.vert'
```

My target is to simply import file content as a string:

```
import SimpleVert from '../../shaders/simple.vert';
```

Any ideas?

P.S. TypeScript version is `3.5.2`

Comment: Are you targeting Node.js, a browser or both?

Comment: @vicvicvic I use latest TypeScript project from `create-react-app`. In `tsconfig.json` `"moduleResolution": "node"`. Also, I would like to know both solutions - node and browser.

Answer (score 1):

`create-react-app` sets up Webpack. You should configure Webpack to import the content of `.vert` files using something like the [`raw-loader`](https://github.com/webpack-contrib/raw-loader)